# Use other CSV separator to export with primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to export a datable (which is created with `primeFaces V6.1`) as a CSV file, but the default separator is ',', I want to change the separator and put ';', the goal is to display it as an array like Table in xls (without changing the configuration from Excel file).

The other problem is with the encoding of my file, how can I change encoding with `primefaces V6.1`?

But I have two constraints:

1. the first I want to stay on the same version of primefaces V6.1
2. the second I have a problem with the XLS file, because if I have more than 20 000 lines in my table I have a memory problem with Tomcat 7 (I do not want to change the mood of Tomcat either).

So my question is, is there a way to change the CSV separator ? or other solution to download a CSV file and display it in a table format.

Comment: You asked a lot of questions in 1 question but I can answer your XLS performance problem you need to use the streaming version else it holds the whole thing in memory using `type="xlsxstream"`. It was added in 6.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1192

Comment: Defining your own CSV separator was added in 7.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/48

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
When I try type="xlsxstream" with my current versio (V6.1) I have the problem with : Excel XSLSX Streaming POI API throws exception , but when i change the version to V7.0 is working. but i don't want change my version this is the problem because it will impact on my other modules.

Comment: I looked for the solution for the problem with xcel XSLSX Streaming POI API and  I found that's we can use the following code to set a string value to a cell:

Cell c = row.createCell(i);
c.setCellValue(text == null ? "" : text ); 

but I don't Know where i can put it exactely.